# Space before and after = sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, whitespace, jslint

JSLint screamed at me today:

```
Missing space between 'CMyInterface' and '='.
var CMyInterface=Class.create({
line 3 character 21
```

I am using prototype, so the

```
Class
```

comes from that. But still - is it REQUIRED that i place a whitespace before and after the = to produce valid code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the space is not required and your code is valid. But for readability, you should include it (them, to be exact) - and JSLinst complains about that.

Comment: What you say makes sense. But JSLint clearly states this as an ERROR. I am misunderstanding how JSLint works?

Comment: @user1018787: Yes. JSLint reports both readability problems (as deemed by Douglas Crockford) and syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, letting the spaces out is correct, as forgetting the `;` at the end of a line.

However JSLint is a tool to ensure best practices and readability, that's why you have such warning.

Keep the spaces away only for minification...